# how to call a native method on a property using hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

Can some one help me with Criteria query for the below sql query?

**select username, toolkit.decrypt(password) as password from user**;

table defination is as follows:

> name varchar2(40)
>
> password varchar2(40)

The above working fine for my oracle db. I have toolkit package. The same query i would like to use with hibernate criteria, How can i write it?

Please help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it your toolkit package at DB side? Then it would be easier to make a stored procedure in order to retrieve that data from hibernate. However, if you have some functionality to retrieve that data at controller server side (let's say, a Java library to retrieve it), I think it's a better chance (that way your pass goes crypted from DB to controller side).

Comment: yes Toolkit is package in my DB

Answer (score 1):

It can done using splProjection.

The below is the code for the same:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession.createCritrria(User.class);
criteria.add(Projections.Property("username"));
criteria.add(Projections.sqlProjection("toolkit.decrypt(password) as password", new String[]{"password"},new Type[]{Hibernate.String}));
```